# What to do about with question that needs major rethinking/revising?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, bump

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow, and then after a day or two of the question getting next to no viewing and no response, I realized that I had asked the question rather poorly. The issue with the question was that I hadn't provided specific context and my question was kind of broad.

So, I clicked on the "edit" button and started to work my specific situation into the wording. In doing so, I realized that the question really needed to be entirely reworded and rethought. So, I scrapped everything I had previously written and rewrote the question to what I believe is a much better form.

But, as I was about to hit submit I realized my question was still unlikely to get any attention, and here is my delimma: When I originally asked my question, it appeared at the top of the SO feed, but got little attention because it was so poorly written. Now that I had rewritten it I figured people would be more likely to answer it.

But if I simply "edited" the question it would not appear at the top of the SO feed; no one would see it even though it was practically a new question. So, I decided to create an entirely new question, under the exact same name, with the new writing. Was this the right thing to do?

I guess the question here is, do I deserve a "second shot" at getting people's attention with my question? If so, what is the protocol for this?

Comment: "But if I simply "edited" the question it would not appear at the top of the SO feed" Yes, it would. Edits bump the question to the front page for those who have the relevant tags marked as favorites, and to the top of the "Active" list for the tags.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I had figured that promoting a question simply because of spelling corrections would be silly, and that therefore an edit of any scope would not put my question back at the top. I should not have assumed... thanks though.